# Angular 7 material mat-tab-group long delay when switching to new tab if current tab has large data table

Tags: angular

In an Angular 7 project, I have a mat-tab-group defined like this:

```
<mat-tab-group id="tab-group" (selectedTabChange)="handleTabChange($event)" [(selectedIndex)]="tabIndx" color="accent">
<mat-tab label="{{rptType.name}}" *ngFor="let rptType of reportTypes" style="height:100%;">
  <ng-template matTabContent >
    <app-report-selection [profModuleType]="profModuleType" [defaultReportType]="rptType" *ngIf="rptType.isEnabled"></app-report-selection>
  </ng-template>        
</mat-tab>
```

Each tab allows the user to create a report, which is essentially just a mat-table.
All works fine until the report (mat-table) starts to get large. When that happens, the UI becomes unresponsive for 4-7 seconds when the user clicks on a new tab, to run a different report.
For example, one report is currently returning over 7,000 records, which is enough to cause this behavior.
The mat-table does not contain any controls or anything with which the user can interact - it just shows data.

I certainly don't want to abandon the tab control, but this delay is unacceptable. It also makes no sense to me. What could be causing the delay? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by removing change detection from the component displaying the table. This was done by adding the following "changeDetection" setting to the component:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush 
})
```

For more details than I will provide here, see https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/optimize-the-performances-of-large-tables-in-your-angular-application/